# Stemming with term vector component in solr

Tags: solr, stemming

I am using term vector component in **solr** for building tag cloud. I am also using porter-stem factory for stemming at index and query time both.

The problem is term vector gives shows stemmed words in final output with term frequency.
Example :- If I search for the word 'communication' it gives me term frequency of 'commune', but i need **communication**. I need stemming only for querying not in term vector. How can i stop this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [copy field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) that doesn't have stemming and query that field to generate your tag cloud.

for example, assuming your current field is called `my_text`, you may have something like this:

First define a new field:

```
<field name="my_text_2" type="my_text_type_2" indexed="true" stored="false" termVectors="true"/>
```

Then copy your text to it at write time:

```
<copyField source="my_text" dest="my_text_2"/>
```

where `my_text_type_2` is the field type where you can set what analyzers you need. It may be a copy of the current field type used for `my_text` but without the stemming.